# Give the general formula for the integer $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, diophantine-equations

**For the following equation:-**
$$a_1+a_2+a_3.....+a_n=a_1a_2a_3.....a_n = n$$
For $a_1,a_2...a_n \in \mathbb Z$, find the general form of the ***integer*** n.

Note that we need $n$ summands/factors

**Note:-** Regarding the explanation of the term "general form":
 For instance, even numbers are of the general form $2m.$ and rational numbers are of the general form $p/q,etc $. I mean it in that way.
PS: My guess is that we have to use some general formula for multivariable diophantine equation but I don't even know what to do if it is a multivariable diophantine equation.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but I would tend to guess that the down-vote is because this is not a 'do my homework for free' service, and because you are generally expected to share your own thoughts and effort if you're expecting others to make that effort for you.

Comment: Many users here always demand effort, what the questioner has tried , etc., which is correct in principle.But here, I do not agree the downvote

Comment: Are there any examples other than $n=1=a_1$?  (also not the downvote).

Comment: Are you sure it is integers you want? So something like $1 + (-1) + 1 + (-1) + 5 = 1 \cdot (-1) \cdot 1 \cdot (-1) \cdot 5 = 5$ would be ok?

Comment: @Peter, you mean you allow some $a_{i}$ to be zero? Then $n = \dots$

Comment: @AndreasCaranti.Yes, they can repeat. And they are integers.

Comment: @Peter  Oh, by all means exclude $0$.  I'd have said it was more interesting if subscript $n$ was not the same as value $n$.  That way we could have things like $1+2+3=1\times 2\times 3$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti.They can be negative or positive, both.

Comment: Of course my example above generalizes to primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: If we exclude the "$=n$" part, then any sequence of the form $a_1=n,a_2=2,a_3,\dots,a_n=1$ works.

Comment: A few examples: $[2,2],[3,2,1],[4,2,1,1],[5,2,1,1,1],[6,2,1,1,1,1]$.

Comment: @Peter I don't think it works for instance with primes $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: @Peter it has to be $n$ summands/factors. It's the same $n$ as the sum.

Comment: How about a community wiki?

Comment: @Peter  $n=2$ can't be solved either.  If $x+y=2$ and $xy=2$ then $x^2-2x+2=0$ which does not have integer roots.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I did not notice that the index of the last $a_j$ is $n$, so we need $n$ summands

Comment: $1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,3,3$ also works... high values of $a_i$ are factorization of $n$, and if something remains it is spread across the ones...

Comment: @AndreasCaranti wouldn't your example work for any integer $n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, regardless of primality?

Comment: @DarthGeek Yes, it does

Comment: @BarryCipra for any $n = 8m$ we have
$$\underbrace{1 + (-1) + 1 + (-1)\ldots + 1  + (-1)}_{4m\text{ terms}} + \underbrace{1 + 1  + \ldots + 1}_{4m-2\text{ terms}} + 2 + 4m$$

Comment: @Sil, right, that's the answer:  $n$ factorized in $q$ terms of sum $s$, and the difference $n-s$ distributed in $n-s$ ones, plus whatever numbers of couples $1,-1$

Comment: @GCab you'd need an even amount of couples $1,-1$ to make the product positive, i.e. this only works if $4\mid (s-q)$.

Comment: @DarthGeek: yes you are right, we need an even amount of couples. And I forgot the third condition, that the number of terms must be $n$ ! Thanks, now the picture is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Systematically considering numbers $n$ from $1$ to $20$ gives the following solutions (written giving product forms only):

$$\begin{align}
1&=1^1\\
5&=5^1\cdot1^2\cdot(-1)^2\\
8&=4^1\cdot2^1\cdot1^4\cdot(-1)^2\\
9&=9^1\cdot1^4\cdot(-1)^4\\
&=3^2\cdot1^5\cdot(-1)^2\\
12&=3^1\cdot2^2\cdot1^7\cdot(-1)^2\\
13&=13^1\cdot1^6\cdot(-1)^6\\
16&=8^1\cdot2^1\cdot1^{10}\cdot(-1)^4\\
&=2^4\cdot1^6\cdot(-1)^6\\
17&=17^1\cdot1^8\cdot(-1)^8\\
20&=5^1\cdot2^2\cdot1^{15}\cdot(-1)^4\quad\text{(but see the Remark at bottom)}
\end{align}$$

Checking the sequence $1,5,8,9,12,13,16,17,20$ at OEIS leads to the sequence of [amenable numbers](https://oeis.org/A100832), which gives a link to a solution by O.P. Lossers in the *Math Monthly*, April, 1998 (vol. 105, no. 4), pg. 368.  Lossers showed that a positive integer $n$ is "amenable" if and only if $n\equiv0,1$ mod $4$ and $n\not=4$.

Here is the gist of Losser's solution (which makes me realize my "systematic" approach overlooked the possibility of negative numbers other than $-1$):

$$\begin{align}
4k+1&=(4k+1)^1\cdot1^{2k}\cdot(-1)^{2k}\\
8k&=(4k)^1\cdot2^1\cdot1^{6k-2}\cdot(-1)^{2k}\\
8k+4&=(4k+2)^1\cdot1^{6k+3}\cdot(-1)^{2k-1}\cdot(-2)^1\quad\text{if }k\ge1
\end{align}$$

If $n=4k+2$, then just one factor can be even, so that the other $4k+1$ factors are odd, in which case the sum of the factors is odd, so cannot equal $n$.

If $n=4k-1$, all the factors are odd and an odd number must be congruent to $-1$ mod $4$, leaving the rest congruent to $1$ mod $4$, which leads to a sum congruent to $1$ mod $4$.  That is, if $2m-1$ factors are congruent to $-1$ mod $4$, then $n-(2m-1)=4k-2m$ factors are congruent to $1$ mod $4$, so that their sum is congruent to $(4k-2m)(1)+(2m-1)(-1)=4k+1\equiv1$ mod $4$.

Finally, the case $n=4$ (i.e., $8k+4$ with $k=0$, which falls outside the scope of the formula $8k+4=(4k+2)^1\cdot1^{6k+3}\cdot(-1)^{2k-1}\cdot(-2)^1$ because the exponents must all be non-negative) is dispatched by hand.

**Remark** (added later):  In retrospect, I realize I very nearly missed finding the OEIS entry for the amenable numbers, and thus Losser's solution.  My "systematic" approach missed the *correct* factorization $20=10^1\cdot1^{15}\cdot(-1)^3\cdot(-2)^1$, but fortunately found an *incorrect* one, $5^1\cdot2^2\cdot1^{15}\cdot(-1)^4$, which is incorrect because it has $1+2+15+4=22$ factors, not $20$.  Entering just $1,5,8,9,12,13,16,17$ at OEIS, of course, still produces the amenable numbers, but if I'd entered $1,5,8,9,12,13,16,17,21$, instead, I'd have gotten nothing.  (On the other hand, I might have still found it *and* realized I'd overlooked the correct factorization for $n=20$, because when an OEIS search produces nothing, I usually try again with just the first portion of the sequence, on the assumption the smaller numbers are less prone to mistakes on my part.)

Answer (score 3):

If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ is positive, then we have the solution
$$
n = n + 1 + (-1) + \dots + 1 + (-1) = n \cdot 1 \cdot (-1) \cdots \cdot 1 \cdot (-1).
$$

---

If $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ is a positive prime, there are no solutions, as
$$
p = a_{1} \cdots a_{p-1} \cdot p
$$
implies that an even number of the $a_{i}$ equals $-1$, but then for
$$
a_{1} + \dots + a_{p-1}
$$
to be zero we need the same number of $a_{i}$ to be $1$, so $p-1$ would be a multiple of $4$, against the assumption.

---

If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 8$ is positive (i.e. $n = 8m$ for some positive integer $m$), then we have the solution

$$\underbrace{1 -1+\ldots + 1  -1}_{4m\text{ terms}} + \underbrace{1  + \ldots + 1}_{4m-2\text{ terms}} + 2 + 4m = \underbrace{1 \cdot (-1)\cdot\ldots \cdot 1 \cdot (-1)}_{4m\text{ terms}} + \underbrace{1 \cdot \ldots \cdot 1}_{4m-2\text{ terms}} \cdot 2 \cdot 4m$$

---

Comment: Doesn't work the first case for $n\equiv 1\pmod{2}?$

Comment: @mfl not if you require $n > 0$ (you'd have an odd amount of $-1$s)

Comment: @DarthGeek Yes, right. Thank you